# Play sound when JLabel "content" changes

Tags: java, swing

I am currently scripting a pager application that sends out an alarm.

Now, there I have multiple JLabels and the JLabel text is set via a connection to my database (via jLabel.setText()...).

What I want to achieve is that every time the JLabel content (by JLabel.setText() ) is being updated, an alarm SoundEffect is going off.

Any ideas how I could "detect" this change of JLabel value or content?

I am using the NetBeans IDE 8.2.

Comment: Short answer, yes there is, no answer, probably not the way you should be doing it.  What I mean by that is, you have an existing workflow which is updating the labels, this workflow should then also play the sound - this way if you want to change what happens when an update occurs, it's decouple from the other workflows

Comment: @MadProgrammer _you have an existing workflow which is updating the labels, this workflow should then also play the sound_ well ... strictly speaking the label's text could be updated from a variety of sources, some of which might not be under the OP's control. Plus - even if all are - it would require smelly duplication. The typical way to _is that every time the JLabel content is being updated_ is to listen to its text property and trigger the sound in that listener.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html

Comment: @kleopatra Then in that case I'd consider some kind of controller to controller the UI from a centralised workflow - I'd find using a `PropertyChangeListener` for this task a code smell - but that's me

Comment: I also believe the UI would not change just on it's own - especially a JLabel. Still then, @kleopatra is right. Just because code smells it can still exist, and the smell might come from 3rd party source you still have to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers,

I ended up calling a method to play the sound
together with the jLabel.setText() method